# Hybris storefront (template developer)

Tags: vue.js, sap-commerce-cloud, storefront

I am vue.js frontend developer and new to hybris, I came to know Hybris comes with a default store front which is written in jsp,js,jquery,css. how to use vue.js in the storefront for implementing or modifying template as per client requirements.

Answer (score 3):

SAP Commerce Cloud also has an Angular storefront called [Spartacus](https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/), which lets you customize CMS components using web components (but this is still an experimental feature): https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/customizing-cms-components/ Also, see [Vue based CMS web component for Spartacus](https://github.com/dunqan/vue-cms-web-component) for an example.

At a high level, the storefront will need to interact with Hybris' OCC (Omni Commerce Connect) REST APIs for the business processes (and even CMS data).

I've no experience on this (and I haven't read the full article), but [Vue Storefront + SAP Commerce: Open-source PWA Storefront Integration (+DEMO)](https://hybrismart.com/2019/02/13/vue-storefront-sap-commerce-open-source-pwa-storefront-integration-demo/) might give you some ideas.

Comment: thanks for the answers. do i need an external store front like vue storefront/ angular storefront  for theme development , i received desings and need to implement those desings , can i just change styling of the existing design themes

Comment: Spartacus has an OOTB theme called sparta: https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/css-architecture/#style-library-versioning If you use Spartacus, you can customize this. If you are going to build everything from scratch, it may be a little more difficult.